# Absolute element in relative parent - does not overlap other parents

Tags: jquery, css

I have simple dialog, positioned absolutely in the center of the screen.
There inside is one simple dropdown with relatively positioned parent(I wish dropdown to follow his parent position without js).
But as I add relative position to his parent element dropdown does not overlap any other elements. This is normal behaviour I supose.

But still I am triing to find pure css solution for this behaviour.

**HTML and CSS**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropDown_open").on("click", function() {
        $(".abs").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

#container .dialog {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 150px);
    top: calc(50% - 150px);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: white;
}

#container .dialog .preScroll {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container .dialog .header,
#container .dialog .footer {
    height: 25px;
}

#container .dialog .scroller {
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    overflow: auto;
}

#container .dialog .scroller #dropDown_open {
    position: relative;
}

#container .dialog .scroller .abs {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 120%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 9999;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    font-size: 16px;
}

ul li:last-child {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="dialog">
        <div class="preScroll">
            <div class="header">header</div>
            <div class="scroller">
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li id="dropDown_open"><span>Click me!</span><div class="abs"></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So shortly: goal is that dropdown will overlap dialog itself if needed - should be visible on the top of the dialog when there is no space left.

Here is jsFiddle(more accurate): http://jsfiddle.net/8p0jj2jk/1/

Answer (score 0):

use the the :hover state like so maybe ?

use the following CSS selector :

```
#container .dialog .scroller #dropDown_open > span:hover ~ div.abs {
    display:block;
}
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/8p0jj2jk/4/)**

Comment: Umm no, unfortunately you didn't understand me, sorry for that. I wish that dropdown(red div) will overlap dialog itself - so it will look outside of dialog if it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understand you clearly.
Try to replace this

```
#container .dialog .scroller .abs { ...; top: 120%; ...; }
```

with

```
#container .dialog .scroller .abs { ...; bottom: 120%; ...; }
```